# How to change font-size in embed HTML's plugin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have written plugin/widget to website example.com which is pasted as .css and .js code. Plugin is mounted on example.com #app element. Site example.com has it's own stylesheet with

```css
html {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

which affect for entire website including my plugin. I've tried

```css
#app {
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

but some of widget's elements have still font-size: 12px property. Both, example.com and my widget using bootstrap 4.

**EDIT:**
Please take a look on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/264383/

Comment: use `!important` : font-size: 16px!important;

Comment: As I saw in fiddle the font size is `16px`

Comment: In the fiddle, thje select element is not styled. Give it a font-size explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

try using `!important` tag.

```
#app{
  font-size:16px!important;
}
```

Comment: this answer has to be a comment

Comment: Using `!important` is not the best practice. Clean code doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of the widget's elements are inheriting the font size from the first css rule. 
One way to do it is to set the font size for all descendant elements of #app like that:

```
#app * {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```